# How to display data from database on jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, blob

So, there is a table in database(MySQL) that contains name and photo(blob). In my web app on main page there is a button, after clicking on it - it has to be another page with all results from database. Im using servlets/jsp/, jdbc and MVC pattern
I have entity User with fields name and photo(byte[]), I have DAO class that returns List, retrieved from database
I want on result page have for each user photo and his name near the photo.

How to do this with servlet/jsp?

Answer (score 0):

Despite there's some obscure [src="data:image/gif;base64,<%=strImage%>"] attribute for img tag, it seems that this is not a reliable way to deal with this.

JSP serves text or binary data, because you set content-type only once for each response.

So I think you'll need to send the html in one jsp, and serve the image in another jsp/servlet.

Comment: I think you'll need to send the html in one jsp, and serve the image in another jsp/servlet What do you mean?

Comment: suppose that you need to open a window with the name of the person and his/her photo. The page that contains the name is one JSP. The url for the photo is a link to another JSP/servlet